# Interpolating sea level data using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, interpolation, excel, sea-level-rise

I have monthly sea level data obtained from PSMSL in the form of excel sheet for the region Chennai.

I want to interpolate the data in ArcGIS Desktop. The shapefile of the region has Polygons and I want to interpolate 26 Points on it to calculate the [CVI](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1999/of99-593/pages/cvi.html).